# How to run a mongodb query with $in and $near commands

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to get the details of the nearest users(selected users)

```
var listData = db.bloodDonarModel.find({_id:{$in:donarIds}}, {location: { $near: [83.307974, 17.716456]}}).limit(10)
```

the mysql equivalent query is like

```
select * from users where user_id IN (1,2,3) and (distance logic);
```

What is the correct query to get the result, Can someone correct me?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried these queries, the result is highlighted with respective colored box
[image]

**Note:**
I have already added an index

```
db.blooddonars.ensureIndex({Location:"2d"})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an *explicit* `$and` in your case. To quote [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/):

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

So, you can simply group several conditions in the *same* query object here:

```
var listData = db.bloodDonarModel.find(
           {
             _id:{$in:donarIds},
             location: { $near: [83.307974, 17.716456]}
           }).limit(10)
```

This will match any document having *both* an `_id` in `donarId` and a `location` near `[83.307974, 17.716456]`.

**Of course, as explained [in the doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/), `$near` requires a geospatial index on the `location` field.** For example:

```
> db.bloodDonarModel.createIndex({location: "2d"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried this earlier. But it gave an error regarding index. Please check my updated post

Comment: @Ramaraju.d *this* is really interesting. I cannot see the error. Have you edited your question ?

Comment: This worked. But it displayed only 5 records instead of 12. It only returned the records that have Location field, It did not display the other 7. I included Location field recently so those 7 documents have no Location field. I also need those 7 to return in the result.

Comment: The index error is due to mismatch in field name "location" instead "Location" is given.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried the obvious?

```
{
    $and : [ {
        _id : { 
            $in : donarIds 
        }
    }, {
        location: {
            $near: [ 83.307974, 17.716456 ]
        }
    }]
}
```

respectively

```
var listData = db.bloodDonarModel.find({ $and : [ { _id : { $in : donarIds }}, { location: { $near: [ 83.307974, 17.716456 ]}}]}).limit(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, An error relating to index is popping.